# Selecting image from gallery not working in android smart phone

Tags: flutter, image, dart, picker

Thanks for review my code!
I am trying to select an image from gallery to show in imageview, but the selection does not works... I can't see photo select page...
BUT it work well in computer-emulator.
It's part of the code

Code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class CreatePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final FirebaseUser user;

CreatePage(this.user);

@override
 _CreatePageState createState() => _CreatePageState();
   }

class. _CreatePageState extends State<CreatePage> {
final textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _getImage();
    }

  @override
  void dispose() {
   textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
      }

   File _image;


  Future _getImage() async {
   var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
   source: ImageSource.gallery,
   maxWidth: 1000,
   maxHeight: 1000,
    );

  setState(() {
     _image = image;
         });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In image picker, PickFile returns XFile,not type file.And also you said max width, height limit for the image pick.

Try this code

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

    XFile? _image;
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    // Pick an image
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

setState(() {
     _image= image ;
         });
      }
```